# What does "AS Name" and "AS Number" mean on the cloudflare DNS check page (https://1.1.1.1/help)?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

What does AS Name and AS Number mean on the cloudflare DNS check page (https://1.1.1.1/help)? i.e. what does "AS" stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"AS" stands for ["Autonomous System"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28Internet%29).

These are large scale networks that provide routing information to other large scale networks. Autonomous systems communicate with each other using the Border Gateway Protocol (BGP).

Related interesting link: https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/security/glossary/what-is-bgp/

The names and numbers can be looked up here: https://asrank.caida.org/